# Best way to figure out why didReceiveMemoryWarning is always getting called on a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, memory-management

I have a UIViewController and I'm noticing that I've done something to where the didReceiveMemoryWarning method is getting called every time I run it on an actual device.

I've run the project with Run > Run With Performance Tool > Object Allocations (and Leaks also).  There are no leaks but I have no idea how to read or understand the "Object Allocations" data that is displayed.

So ...

How do I read this information and what is/are the best ways to figure out (and resolve) why this is happening?

Thanks

EDIT:
I should mention that I also have a number of 3rd party libraries/code that I've included in my project (e.g. Three20, MGTwitterEngine, FTUtils, extThree20JSON and Twitter+OAuth).  Could this be causing this??? Or at least contributing to the problem?

EDIT #2:
Don't know if this helps but I notice that this is happening either everytime that I present a UIImagePickerController modally -OR- after a take a picture using it.

*** UPDATE ***

Ran it again with the Object Alloc tool for several minutes and I don't see anymore than 4.75MB being allocated at any given moment.  The app was running on a device and typically with 2.5 MB allocated on average.

Does this seem problematic to anyone???  Seems like its in an acceptable range insofar as I understand thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with UIImagePickerController ... and all is answered in this post: [Received memory warning. Level=1 when showing a UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099029/received-memory-warning-level1-when-showing-a-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 0):

This may happen some time when your device have less memory free to use. Check your device free memory.

Comment: How do you do this on a 3gs phone?