# iPhone iOS 4.0 Camera FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -1

Tags: iphone, ios4, camera

Since I updated to 4.0, when I take a photo with my App using UIImagePickerController I get the following error output:

> *** ERROR: FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -1. Input (null) was 711733 bytes.

I still get the image returned and can continue as normal, but does any body know what and why I get this  error. I also get the following warnings that could be related:

> Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this >application must remove two-stage method implementations.
>
> Using two-stage rotation animation is not supported when rotating more than one view >controller or view controllers not the window delegate

Any information would be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alan, did you resolve the issue with didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo being called twice? I'm experiencing the same thing in my app. I've tracked it down to showing a UIProgressView that I pop up over the UIImagePickerController UI while I do some processing in a second thread. I don't (and don't want to) dismiss the UIImagePickerController while I process the image. This didn't happen in 3.0 and doesn't happen on the 4.0 Simulator, only 4.0 device.

Comment: Regarding the error - have a look <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099029/received-memory-warning-level1-when-showing-a-uiimagepickercontroller/3321000#3321000">here</a>

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting it as well. I also haven't found any real solution for it yet. I've tried just about everything I can think of and I'm getting some EXC_BAD_ACCESS right after it which I'm sure it probably related, but if anyone has found out more about this error, it sure would be nice to get a resolution to it.

Comment: The warnings are not related to the error and are not catastrophic.  The image picker uses two stage rotation, but is typically used between multiple controllers, probably your current view controller and the UIImagePickerController.  I have seen another thread about this warning and while there were a lot of theories about it, no one posted a usable workaround.  While there might be a workaround found, Apple should update the picker to conform to its normal usage.

Comment: I am having the exact same error. Using iOS 4.1. No solution yet.

Comment: I have solved this, read my edited post

Answer (score 1):

I also have problems with UIImagePickerController on iOS 4.0,
It works on simulator on 3.0 but on 4.0 i have a crash the delegate method 
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
is called twice, and if i build on the phone and use camera it works ok.

Edit:

I have solved this problem long time ago by adding a global static int and when i enter the delegate method I test for that static int the I increment the value of it. And in the way the delegate is executed only once.

Comment: I have XCode 4 and running the app on iPhone 3G, and this solution unfortunately this doesn't solve error.