# FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone app development, while taking picture from camera I am getting the **FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned** error. Can any one help me out to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629785/ios-4-figcreatecgimagefromjpeg-returned-1). Could be the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned will not cause any problem in the application, even if you get the **"FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned"** error the application will not be crash.

You may get this error over simulator only it will not affect the application after installing it over device.

Comment: in my simulator its working fine but not working fine on device

Comment: same here, its coming on device, not on simulator